# How to write a Show instance for Mu recursive types

Tags: haskell, show, recursive-datastructures, fixpoint-combinators

I want to write an instance of `Show` for lists of the following type:

```
newtype Mu f = Mu (forall a. (f a -> a) -> a)
data ListF a r = Nil | Cons a r deriving (Show)
type List a = Mu (ListF a)
```

Module [Data.Functor.Foldable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html) defines it, but it converting it to `Fix`, something I want to avoid.

How can I define this `Show` instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The slogan, *"Follow the types!"*, works for us here, fulltime.

From your code, with some renaming for easier comprehension,

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data ListF a r = Nil | Cons a r deriving (Show)
newtype List a = Mu {runMu :: forall r. (ListF a r -> r) -> r}
```

So that we can have

```
fromList :: [a] -> List a
fromList (x:xs) = Mu $ \g -> g   -- g :: ListF a r -> r
                               (Cons x $                 -- just make all types fit
                                  runMu (fromList xs) g)
fromList []     = Mu $ \g -> g Nil

{-   or, equationally,
runMu (fromList (x:xs)) g = g (Cons x $ runMu (fromList xs) g)
runMu (fromList [])     g = g Nil 

     such that (thanks, @dfeuer!)
runMu (fromList [1,2,3]) g = g (Cons 1 (g (Cons 2 (g (Cons 3 (g Nil))))))
-}
```

and we want

```
instance (Show a) => Show (List a) where
 -- show :: List a -> String
 show (Mu f) = "(" ++ f showListF ++ ")"            -- again, just make the types fit
```

... we must produce a string; we can only *call* `f`; what could be its argument? According to its type,

```
  where
  showListF :: Show a => ListF a String -> String   -- so that, f showListF :: String !
  showListF Nil        = ...
  showListF (Cons x s) = ...
```

There doesn't seen to be any other way to connect the wires here.

With this, `print $ fromList [1..5]` prints `(1 2 3 4 5 )`.

Indeed this turned out to be a verbose version of [chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959/chi)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50947092/849891).

*edit:* `g` is for "algebra" (thanks, @chi!) and `f` (in `Mu f`) is for "folding". Now the meaning of this type becomes clearer: given an "algebra" (a  reduction function), a `Mu f` value will use it in the folding of its "inherent list" represented by this "folding function". It represents the folding of a list with one-step reduction semantics, using it on *each* step of the folding.

Answer (score 2):

Define your own algebra first

```
showOneLayer :: Show a => ListF a String -> String
showOneLayer ... = ...
```

Then,

```
instance Show a => Show (Mu (ListF a)) where
   show (Mu f) = f showOneLayer
```

Comment: @user3368561 Yes, I think so.

Comment: It is possible to make it generic on the functor `f` given it provides a `Show` instance?

Comment: @user3368561 I think it depends on the instance. As long as you can get an algebra as the one above you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As WillNess showed, you probably want a `newtype` to wrap your `List`:

```
newtype Mu f = Mu {reduce :: forall a. (f a -> a) -> a}
-- I've added a field name for convenience.

data ListF a r = Nil | Cons a r
  deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
  -- You'll probably want these other instances at some point.

newtype List a = List {unList :: Mu (ListF a)}
```

WillNess also wrote a useful `fromList` function; here's another version:

```
fromList :: Foldable f => f a -> List a
fromList xs =
  List $ Mu $ foldr (\a as g -> g (Cons a (as g))) ($ Nil) xs
```

Now let's write a basic (not quite right) version. I'll turn on `ScopedTypeVariables` to add type signatures without annoying duplication.

```
instance Show a => Show (List a) where
  showsPrec _ xs = reduce (unList xs) go
    where
      go :: ListF a ShowS -> ShowS
      go Nil = id
      go (Cons x r) = (',':) . showsPrec 0 x . r
```

This will show a list, sort of:

```
show (fromList []) = ""
show (fromList [1]) = ",1"
show (fromList [1,2]) = ",1,2"
```

Hrm. We need to install the leading `[` and the trailing `]`, and somehow deal with the extra leading comma. One good way to do that is to keep track of whether we're on the first list element:

```
instance Show a => Show (List a) where
  showsPrec _ (List xs) = ('[':) . reduce xs go False . (']':)
    where
      go :: ListF a (Bool -> [Char] -> [Char]) -> Bool -> [Char] -> [Char]
      go Nil _ = id
      go (Cons x r) started =
        (if started then (',':) else id)
        . showsPrec 0 x
        . r True
```

Now we actually show things properly!

But actually, we've gone to quite a bit more trouble than necessary. All we really needed was a `Foldable` instance:

```
instance Foldable List where
  foldr c n (List (Mu g)) = g $ \case
    Nil -> n
    Cons a as -> c a as
```

Then we can write

```
instance Show a => Show (List a) where
  showsPrec p xs = showsPrec p (toList xs)
```

Comment: this is nice. the `g`-juggling in your `fromList` was a bit of a mind bender, until I finally gave up and wrote down some sample expansion (for `[1,2,3]`) by hand. which actually clarified things for me. :) I could even simplify it a bit, as `fromList xs = List $ Mu $ \g -> foldr (g .: Cons) (g Nil) xs`. which also makes it lazier? (is this good?). and doing `Foldable` getting its `toList` for free is a great idea (I skipped over everything in the middle). :) seems obvious in retrospect, like all great ideas do.

Comment: @WillNess, what is lazier about that? Also, what is `.:`? My `fromList` is based directly on yours.

Comment: I thought `foldr ... _|_` would diverge but `\g -> foldr ... _|_` wouldn't. --- Yes after working through your version I realized it is the same as in my answer (I didn't try hard enough to expand it out, was content that the pieces fit... ). But after finally seeing that after series of applications we're left with this `g (Cons a (g (Cons b (g Nil))))` thing, I thought, why not just code it that way? --- re: [`.:`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-Composition.html#v:.:) I thought it is part of common lore. :)