# How to write a Show instance for the Mu recursive type

Tags: haskell, show, functor

Due to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946004/how-to-write-a-show-instance-for-mu-recursive-types), I know how to write specialized instances for particular `Mu` recursive types like `Mu NatF` or `Mu (ListF a)`. Now I want to write a generic instance that works for all functors applied to `Mu`.

Basically what I want to do is to fill the gap named `<???>` in the following Haskell snipet:

```
newtype Mu f = Mu (forall a. (f a -> a) -> a)

instance (Functor f, Show1 f) => Show (Mu f) where
    showsPrec d (Mu f) = <???>
```

How can this be accomplished?

**EDIT**

Imagine I want to define natural numbers using `Mu`. Like this:

```
data NatF r = Zero | Succ r

instance Functor NatF where
  fmap f Zero = Zero
  fmap f (Succ r) = Succ (f r)

type NatMu = Mu NatF
```

Now I want to show values of type `NatMu`, so I do this:

```
instance Show (Mu NatF) where
    show (Mu f) = f alg where
        alg Zero = "Zero"
        alg (Succ n) = "(Succ " ++ n ++ ")"
```

Everything works and everybody is happy, but... What if I want to define `data NatNu = Nu NatF` or `data ListMu a = Mu (ListF a)`? I will need to create a practically identical instance for each variation. Why not to abstract it so my definitions only grow linearly with number of functors and recursive schemes and not quadratically?

I have no idea how to do it. I am just learning Haskell from a heavy assembly+C background (embedded programming and numerical code). My brain shortcuts with those abstractions, types, lifting... I am trying to understand it implementing most basic concepts from scratch, but I can solve this particular problem.

**EDIT2**

I managed to write something that works, but it looks odd to me. Moreover, it needs some ugly extensions like `UndecidableInstances`.

```
instance Show (NatF String) where
    show Zero = "Zero"
    show (Succ n) = "(Succ " ++ n ++ ")"

instance (Functor f, Show (f String)) => Show (Mu f) where
    show (Mu f) = f $ show
```

Is there a better way to do it (without the need of fancy Haskell extensions)?

Comment: So how is this different from [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946004/how-to-write-a-show-instance-for-mu-recursive-types), what merits asking a new one, and once again: _what have you tried_?

Answer (score 2):

First let me rewrite your `Mu NatF` instance to define `showsPrec` instead of `show`, which is generally the preferred way (and will become important in a moment).

```
instance Show (Mu NatF) where
  showsPrec p (Mu f) = showParen (p>9) $ f alg where
     alg :: NatF ShowS -> ShowS
     alg Zero = ("Zero"++)
     alg (Succ n) = ("(Succ "++) . n . (")"++)
```

Nothing much changed here; I've basically just replaced the `++` concatenation operator with composition-concatenation of difference lists. (The reason these are preferred is mainly the annoying *O* (*n*<sup>2</sup>) complexity of left-associative list concatenations; it's a bit of a historical embarrassment.)

Now if you want to switch to other functors, the only thing that needs to change is the `alg` function. You need a generic

```
alg :: Show1 f => f ShowS -> ShowS
```

Well, that's *almost* [the function which the `Show1` class is about](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html#v:showsPrec1):

```
showsPrec1 :: (Show1 f, Show a) => Int -> f a -> ShowS
```

(This is basically equivalent to `show1 :: (Show1 f, Show a) => f a -> String`, which isn't shipped in the libraries though.)

You just need to instead of *showing* the `a` argument simply paste in a `ShowS` as verbatim. I'd do this with a hack:

```
newtype UnquotedString = UnquotedString {getUnquotedString :: ShowS}

instance Show UnquotedString where
  showsPrec _ (UnquotedString s) = s
```

We always want parentheses; this can be achieved by always giving 10 to the precedence argument.

```
alg = showsPrec1 10 . fmap UnquotedString
```

---

IMO, this whole approach with `Show1` is rather awkward though. That is an annoying-to-instantiate class, much different from `Show` which you can simply derive. Therefore, I actually find your approach with the `(Functor f, Show (f String))` neater. Don't care to much about `-XUndecidableInstances` – that's needed because you “re-call” the class in a way so the compiler won't end up in a loop while typechecking, but this isn't such a big concern.

You still need to avoid the extra quotes with this approach, though.

Comment: I'm already using `showsPrec`, but because it was longer and less obvious, I changed it to the simpler `show` interface to post it here. Regarding your answer (very helpful), how will be the `instance (Show1 NatF)`? I tryied to implement it without success...

Comment: Ok. I did it. Now I have problems understanding what is `fmap UnquotedString` doing and why when I remove it it doesn't type-checks.

Comment: It doesn't typecheck without the `UnquotedString` wrapper because `ShowS` is a function type under the hood, and as such can't be shown directly.